# How to implement transfer method for a account class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

So, I'm making a Account class in python. It has the basic functions of deposit, withdrawing, and checking your balance. I'm having trouble with a transfer method though.
This is my code(sorry for the code dump):

```
class Account:
    """simple account balance of bank"""
    def __init__ (self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        print('Account of ' + self.name)
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount > 0:
            self.balance += amount
            self.statement()
    def withdrawal(self, amount):
        if amount > 0 and self.balance > amount:
            self.balance -= amount
            self.statement()
        else:
            print("the ammount in your is not sufficent")
            self.statement()
    def statement(self):
        print("Hi {} your current balance is {}".format(self.name,self.balance))
    def transfer(self, amount, name):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
        name.balance = name.balance + amount 
        return name.balance()
```

Now, it works for

```
abc = Account("abc", 0)
abc.deposit(1000)
siddharth = Account("siddharth", 159)
```

So how do I run following code:

```
siddharth.transfer(11, "abc")
siddharth.transfer(11, Account.abc)
```

also, how do I create account "abc" if account "abc" doesn't exist

Comment: The problem is that you wrote the transfer method expecting `name` to be a Account object (you are calling `name.balance`) while name is actually a `str`(`"abc"`)

Comment: Show how should I define the transfer function, I want the function to transfer the amount to another object of the same class

Comment: thanks, @PatrickArtner but the interpreter says ""TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"' I want to be able to use the Account name, not the name I gave it if that makes any sense? So I want to it say Siddharth has transferred 11 to account abc

siddharth.transfer(11,abc)
I just have no idea how to do this.

Comment: One way is to have a find function to first find the account object before transferring. After you find the object, you can pass it in transfer() method. If not found, you can create an object and pass it in siddarth.transfer()

Comment: `siddharth.transfer(11, abc)`

Comment: @Siddharth Dash, You're getting the `TypeError` because you're trying to return `name.balance()` as a function, when it is a data attribute. Remove the parentheses and `siddharth.transfer(11, abc)` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be your best lesson about taking care of variables/parameters naming. Your method `transfer(self, amount, name)` should be `transfer(self, amount, account)`. I think that now, it will be obvious that the correct code is

```
abc = Account("abc", 0)
abc.deposit(1000)
siddharth = Account("siddharth", 159)
siddharth.transfer(11, abc)
```

Be really careful on misleading names.

Aside of your question, I don't think that an Account should have a *transfer* method. An *Account* only cares about deposits and withdraws, not about what is done with them. IMO *Transfer* should be a function with 2 `Account` parameters, withdrawing from the first, making a deposit on the second. This is just to follow the Single Responsibility principle.

Following the same principle, don't put print functions in an Account. Consider that you don't know the context in which your class will be used. If it is in a web app, prints are redirected to /dev/null…

Finally, always do what you said you'll do. If I have an account with a balance b, I expect that after the call to deposit with a value v, my account balance will be b + v. No matter the value of v. You are right to check the value and not adding a negative value (that is a withdraw) so you have to warn the caller that you'll not add the value, so rise an exception. Same for withdraw.

Answer (score 0):

You can first have an array of all accounts somewhere declared. Then, you can first try to find if an account exists. If not, create an account and pass them.

```
allAccounts = []

#create bunch of accounts including 'abc'

siddharth = Account("siddharth", 159)

searchResult = [x for x in allAccounts if x.name == 'abc']
#assuming that account names are unique
if len(searchResult) == 0:
   acc = Account("abc", 11)
else:
   acc = searchResult[0]

siddarth.transfer(11, acc)
```